# Leer archivos con python, problema al obtener valor con .readline()

Tags: python, python-2.7

tengo un inconveniente al querer ejecutar como parámetros o variables los datos que extraigo de un archivo txt.
Por ejemplo:

```
conexion = kinterbasdb.connect(dsn=str(dir),user=str(user), password=str(password))
 global variable1
 variable1 = 'C:/carpeta/etc/'
```

Y `dir` es una variable donde almaceno el dato extraído de un txt:

```
    dir_tb= variable1
    archivo = open('texto.txt','w') 
    archivo.write(dir_tb+"\n")

    archivo = open('texto.txt','r') 
    dir = archivo.readline()
```

Pero si reemplazo el parámetro `dir` por la variable global funciona bien.

Comment: Cuando dices que no funciona, ¿da algún error que pueda dar alguna pista? ¿tienes en cuenta que `readline` devuelve la línea completa, incluido los caracteres de fin de línea? Y por cierto, `dir` es el nombre de una función común de python. NO la uses como nombre de variable.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @ChemaCortes, efectivamente el estaba en la linea de lectura. La solución fue eliminar los espacios con line[0].strip()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentas que cuando usas :

```
variable1 = 'C:/carpeta/etc/'
```

como valor para definir  `dsn=str(dir)` y funciona, pero si lees el valor del archivo no funciona:

```
dir = archivo.readline()
```

Deberia funcionar sin ningun problema, te sugiero que revises que valor se tiene en la linea que se obtiene del archivo

```
print 'valor de dir : ',  str(file.readline())
```

te podría asegurar que el problema es que la linea que estas leyendo del archivo, no contiene en realidad el valor  `'C:/carpeta/etc/'`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Elenasys, efectivamente el estaba en la linea de lectura. La solución fue eliminar los espacios con `line[0].strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por tu respuesta @ChemaCortes @Elenasys, efectivamente el estaba en la linea de lectura. La solución fue eliminar los espacios con `line[0].strip()`